# Проблемы с кодировкой получаемых писем

Tags: кодировка, email, html-form

Всем привет! 
Проблема скоре всего избитая, но каждый случай индивидуален. Оговорюсь - не программист, продвинутый пользователь. Для сайта использовал покупной шаблон.
Проблема: иероглифы в письме с формы заказа, особенно в том случае, если все сообщения системы типа "Thank You! Your message has been sent" перевести на русский "Спасибо, бла-бала-бла". На латинице - все ок.
Когда письмо приходит на почту, то в списке писем в поле от кого отображается некорректно - тоже иероглифы, если кириллица. 
Когда видишь само письмо в The Bat, то тjn же текст в поле от кого кириллица отображаются иероглифами, в теле письма кириллица - иероглифами. А корректно отображаются только латинские буквы и e-mail отправителя. 
Если сделать ручками Перекодировка в настройках письма на UTF-8, то все начинает отображаться корректно. Пример полученного письма:
Заголовок: РРіРѕСЂСЊ Р’РёРєС‚РѕСЂРѕРІРёС‡

### Само письмо:

Name: РРіРѕСЂСЊ Р’РёРєС‚РѕСЂРѕРІРёС‡
Email: webmaster@webname.kiev.ua
Message:

### РЅРёРєР°РєРѕР№

Что имеем.
В html head meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8".
Отправкой письма, видимо, рулят два файла, я их код ниже вставил.
Как побороть проблему?
Был бы рад получить код, который надо вставить в файл (-ы)
---- первый файл - contact.php ----

```
<?php

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = '<strong>Error!</strong> Please enter a valid email address';
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure message were entered
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!$hasError) {
        $emailTo = 'boss@iz.ua'; //Put your own email address here
        $subject = 'Message from your website'; //Put your own subject here
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $message";
        $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\nReply-To: ".$email."";

        $sent = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        if ($sent) {
                //If message is sent
                echo "SEND"; 
            } else {
                //If errors are found
                echo "Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information and try again. Thank you."; 
            }
    } else {
        echo $hasError; //If errors are found
    }

?>
```

--- Второй файл form.php --------------

```
<?php
    if (!function_exists('http_response_code'))
    {
        function http_response_code($newcode = NULL)
        {
            static $code = 200;
            if($newcode !== NULL)
            {
                header('X-PHP-Response-Code: '.$newcode, true, $newcode);
                if(!headers_sent())
                    $code = $newcode;
            }
            return $code;
        }
    }

    // My modifications to mailer script from:

     // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "boss@iz.ua";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact DOMAIN";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

В form.php надо кодировку поставить.
Замените

```
$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
```

на

```
$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>/r/n" . "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

Comment: Заменил. Тема письма пришла без иероглифов.  А вот поле От и само письмо  пришли с иероглифами.

Comment: И на сайте сообщение об отправке тоже иероглифами , т.е.���! ���� ��������� ����������! А должно быть Ура! Ваше сообщение отправлено!